# How to calculate the sum of array of UInt16 values in swift?

Tags: ios, higher-order-functions, swift5

How to calculate the sum of an array of UInt16 values in swift5.
Below I am sharing my code,

```
let myArray: [UInt16] = [23200, 23200, 23300, 23300, 23200, 23300, 23200]
let sumOfArray = myArray.reduce(0, { $0 + $0 })
print("sum of myArray is  \(sumOfArray)")
```

When I am calculating the sum of array values, it is giving an error as 
"Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)."

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UInt16` is 16bit, hence max unsigned integer value it can hold is 65535. Which is smaller than your result sum 162700.

Use

```
let myArray: [UInt16] = [23200, 23200, 23300, 23300, 23200, 23300, 23200]
let sumOfArray = myArray.reduce(0, { (UInt32($0) + UInt32($1)) })
print("sum of myArray is  \(sumOfArray)")
```

or even more robust

```
let sumOfArray = myArray.reduce(0, { $0 + UInt($1)) })
```

Btw I believe you have a typo and in your `reduce` you meant `$0 + $1`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Kamil's answer,

You can use overflow operator if you need to use return UInt16 only:

```
let myArray: [UInt16] = [23200, 23200, 23300, 23300, 23200, 23300, 23200]
let sumOfArray = myArray.reduce(0, {$0 &+ $1 })
print("sum of myArray is  \(sumOfArray)")
```

Comment: But obviously, because of the overflow, `sumOfArray` won’t actually represent the sum of the numbers, but rather some unintelligible value.

Comment: @Rob True, but if we need to process the value in UInt16 in our app then also we need to downcast. This can be used when we would need the value in UInt16.

Comment: Fine, but then don’t call it a “sum” because it’s no longer a numeric total of the values. It comes down to what the purpose of the calculated total. E.g. if averaging the values, create 32 or 64 bit sum, divide by the number of items in the array and only then recast the result back to 16 bits of necessary. But I there are very few cases where the truncated 16-bit “sum” has any utility.